# Spivak, Ch. 15 "Trigonometric Functions", Problem 18b: What is $\arcsin{(\cos{x})}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

The following is a problem from Ch. 15 "Trigonometric Functions" from Spivak's *Calculus*.

**I provide the solution manual solution, and then my own version which includes many intermediate steps.** My question is if my version is actually correct.

> 18. (a) Prove that $\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\cos{x}$.
>
> (b) What is $\arcsin{(\cos{x})}$ and $\arccos{(\sin{x})}$?

Proving $(a)$ is simple: $\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{x}\cdot 0+\cos{x}\cdot 1=\cos{x}$.

My question is about part $(b)$.

**Here is the solution manual solution** to find what $\arcsin{(\cos{x})}$ is

> Part $(a)$ implies that $x+\pi/2=\arcsin{(\cos x)}$ for $-\pi/2\leq
>  x+\pi/2\leq \pi/2$, or equivalently $-\pi\leq x\leq 0$. If
> $x=2k\pi+x'$ for $-\pi\leq x\leq 0$ (note that it says $x$ here, but I think it is a typo and should be $x'$), then $\cos{x}=\cos{x'}$, and if
> $x=2k\pi+x'$ for $0\leq x'\leq \pi$, then
> $\cos{x}=\cos{x'}=\cos{(-x')}$. So
>
> $$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=\begin{cases} x-2k\pi+\pi/2, \text{ for }
>  (2k-1)\pi\leq x\leq 2k\pi \\ 2k\pi+\pi/2-x, \text{ for } 2k\pi\leq x
>  \leq (2k+1)\pi \end{cases}$$

**Let me try to step through this filling in some intermediate steps.** My question is if the following is correct?

From part $(a)$, we have $$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\cos{x}$$

and this is true for all $x$.

We would like to take the $\arcsin$ of each side. However, it is only true that

$$\arcsin{\sin{(x+\pi/2)}}=x+\pi/2$$

if $x+\pi/2 \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, which means $x\in [-\pi,0]$

If this is the case then

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=x+\pi/2$$

If, on the other hand, $x+\pi/2\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, then

$$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{(\pi-x-\pi/2)}=\cos{x}\tag{1}$$

and

$$\pi-x-\pi/2 \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$

so from $(1)$ we obtain

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=\pi-x-\pi/2$$

At this point we have

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=\begin{cases} x+\pi/2, \text{ for } x\in[-\pi,0] \\ \pi-x-\pi/2, \text{ for } x\in [0,\pi] \end{cases}$$

What happens if $x=2\pi k+x'$ for $x'\in [-\pi,0]$?

Then $x+\pi/2=2\pi k +x'+\pi/2$

and

$$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{(2\pi k +x'+\pi/2)}=\sin{(x'+\pi/2)}=\sin{(x-2\pi k+\pi/2)}$$

Thus, taking $\arcsin$

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=x-2\pi k +\pi/2$$

Similarly, if $x=2\pi k+x'$ for $x'\in [0,\pi]$ then as before $x+\pi/2=2\pi k+x'+\pi/2$ but now these expressions are in $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$.

Thus

$$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{(2\pi k +x'+\pi/2)}=\sin{(x'+\pi/2)}=\sin{(x-2\pi k+\pi/2)}$$

$$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{(\pi-x-\pi/2)}=\sin{(\pi-2\pi k - x'-\pi/2)}=\sin{(\pi-x'-\pi/2)}$$

$$=\sin{(\pi/2-x+2\pi k)}$$

Note that $\pi/2-x+2\pi k = \pi/2-x' \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Thus we have

$$\sin{(x+\pi/2)}=\sin{(\pi/2-x+2\pi k)}=\cos{x}$$

And we can take the $\arcsin$ to obtain

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=\pi/2-x+2\pi k$$

At this point we have shown what $\arcsin{x}$ is for all values of $x$

$$\arcsin{(\cos{x})}=\begin{cases} x-2\pi k +\pi/2, \text{ for } -\pi+2\pi k \leq x \leq 2\pi k \\ \pi/2-x+2\pi k, \text{ for } 2\pi k\leq x\leq 2\pi k +\pi \end{cases}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: correct but useless algebraic manipulation for the first case just take k=-m with the second case just write inequalities

Answer (score 1):

Here are some properties for $f(x)=\arcsin(\cos(x))$.

1. For $x\in[0,\pi]$, we have $f(x)=\frac\pi2-x$.
2. $f(x)$ is even because $\cos(x)$ is even, for $x\in\mathbb R$.
3. $f(x)$ has a period of $2\pi$ because $\cos(x)$ has a period of $2\pi$.

Using these properties, we can see that $f(x)$ is a triangular wave of amplitude $\frac\pi2$ and period $2\pi$, with $f(0)=\frac\pi2$.

So your result is equivalent to this.

Comment: In 2 you should say "even".